# Proving $\frac{3}{4}+ab+bc+ac\leq a+b+c$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b, c\in (0,1)$ such that, $abc=(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)$.
Show that $\frac{3}{4}+ab+bc+ac\leq a+b+c$.

---

My idea: I denote $p=a+b+c, q=ab+bc+ac, r=abc$. Then $1+q=2r+p$. I have to prove that $r\leq \frac{1}{8}$. Now I am stuck.

Answer (score 4):

Using the relation we get
$a +b + c = 1 + ab + bc + ca -2abc  
= \frac{1}{4}- 2abc + \frac{3}{4} + ab +bc +ca $

Now
Using AM-GM:

$(a+b+c) \ge 3\sqrt[3]{(abc)}$

And
$(1-a)+ (1-b) + (1-c) \ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc} $

$ \implies 3- (a+b+c) \ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}$ (by the relation)

Adding the two inequations we get

$\sqrt[3]{abc} \le \frac{1}{2}$

on cubing both sides and multiplying $-2$ both sides and adding $\frac{1}{4}$ both sides.

We get $\frac{1}{4} -2abc \ge 0$

So using this result we get
$a +b + c \ge \frac{3}{4} +ab + bc +ca$

Comment: Its a maybe +1 for me but isn't the solution unnecessarily long? Or am I wrong?